# Unexpected slow iteration over DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare all lines of a csv file against each other. What I want to do is to get the squared sum of the differences between each two rows:

`np.sum((row_i-row_j)**2)`

I did this using python csv library and it was ok, but I want to use pandas and for some reason, pandas is extremely slow.

My code using csv:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    header = reader.__next__()
    table = list(reader)

for i in range(len(table)-1):
    row_i = np.array(table[i][2:-2], dtype='double')
    for j in range(i+1, len(table)):
        row_j = np.array(table[j][2:-2], dtype='double')
        u = np.sum((row_i - row_j)**2)
```

My code using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)
lines_to_remove2=set()
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    row_i = df.iloc[i][2:-2].values
    for j in range(i+1,len(df)):
        row_j = df.iloc[j][2:-2].values
        u = np.sum((row_i - row_j)**2)
```

As you can see I'm not doing any comparation yet, I'm only assigning values for each row. I will further use the value of `u` to decide which lines will be deleted.
My file has 480 rows which means there are 480*479 iterations, which is not so much. When I iterate over a list, it takes me less than 1s to iterate over all rows, but it takes me many seconds to do it with a pandas.DataFrame. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a faster way of doing this in pandas?

Comment: `for row in list` and `for row in df` are going to be (roughly)equally slow(maybe even slower in pandas) ... you do vector operations on dataframes to speed them up ... not loop over them ... if you can better describe what you are actually trying to do we can probably help answer that

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with that snippet of pandas.  The code doesn't match the title of your question, but in any case iterating is not a good option with pandas

Comment: I want to get the squared sum of the differences between two lines to check if they are to similar to each other. I edited the question with more information.

Comment: `squared sum` I assume you mean sum of counts?  How many lines is your csv file?

Comment: I mean the sum of the square of the differences: `sum(([1.1,1.2] - [1.0,1.0])**2) = 0.1**2 + 0.2**2`. The number of lines is 480. It is described in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs very slow, because you used 2 nested loops and access
each row of *df* by its index.

To get printouts of reasonable size, I used the source DataFrame with only 5 rows:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  3.5
1  2.0  3.6
2  3.0  4.7
3  4.0  6.8
4  5.0  7.3
```

Another simplification is that I compute the result for **whole** rows,
instead of "[2:-2]" part.

To get the result of your code, I ran:

```
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    row_i = df.iloc[i].values
    for j in range(i+1,len(df)):
        row_j = df.iloc[j].values
        difr = row_i - row_j
        u = np.sum(difr**2)
        print(f'{i}, {j}: {row_i}, {row_j}, {difr}, {u}')
```

getting (with added title row):

```
i  j  row_i      row_j      difr         sum_of_squares
0, 1: [1.  3.5], [2.  3.6], [-1.  -0.1], 1.01
0, 2: [1.  3.5], [3.  4.7], [-2.  -1.2], 5.44
0, 3: [1.  3.5], [4.  6.8], [-3.  -3.3], 19.89
0, 4: [1.  3.5], [5.  7.3], [-4.  -3.8], 30.439999999999998
1, 2: [2.  3.6], [3.  4.7], [-1.  -1.1], 2.21
1, 3: [2.  3.6], [4.  6.8], [-2.  -3.2], 14.239999999999998
1, 4: [2.  3.6], [5.  7.3], [-3.  -3.7], 22.689999999999998
2, 3: [3.  4.7], [4.  6.8], [-1.  -2.1], 5.409999999999998
2, 4: [3.  4.7], [5.  7.3], [-2.  -2.6], 10.759999999999998
3, 4: [4.  6.8], [5.  7.3], [-1.  -0.5], 1.25
```

And now how to compute the same result (actually, only the last column of
the above printout) **much** quicker. Run:

```
arr = df.values
difr = arr[:, np.newaxis] - arr[np.newaxis, :]
difr2 = difr * difr
ss = difr2.sum(axis=2)
result = ss[np.triu_indices(arr.shape[0], 1)]
```

The result is:

```
array([ 1.01,  5.44, 19.89, 30.44,  2.21, 14.24, 22.69,  5.41, 10.76, 1.25])
```

To fully comprehend how this code works, run is stepwise and print the result
of each step.

And to use this code in your environment, i.e. take the source DataFrame
without first 2 and last 2 columns, change the first line to:

```
arr = df.values[:, 2:-2]
```

And as far as execution speed is concerned: I compared execution times
of your code (without printout and with added assembling of the sums
of squares in a list) with mine code, using *%timeit* and I got:

- 5.75 ms for your code,
- 206 µs for my code.

Almost 28 times faster.

And for a bigger source data sample the difference should be yet greater.

## Edit

Yet another remark: Your final goal is (probably) to inspect the
resulting sums of squares (for each pair of source rows) and work out
a decision which source rows do drop.

So maybe the source for this assessment should be *ss* array, not
the flattened copy of its upper triangle.

Of course, you should still process the upper triangle of *ss*, but
when you operate on *ss* you have indices of elements, which are equal to
indices of both source rows.

Comment: Thank you for you solution. It works for me. You are right about my final goal. I'm comparing designs and I want to select the best designs as input for a pattern search algorithm. Since the pattern search is a local minimization algorithm, if I try designs that are to similar to each other I will end up in the same optimized design. The last column of my dataframe give me an information about the quality of each design, and the data between 2:-2 are my design parameters.

Comment: At the end if the ss value is too low for solutions i and j, I have to compare the value of the last column of them to decided which one will be discarded.

Comment: Caution: "2:-2" index means that you omit first 2 columns and last 2 columns.
But you wrote that only the **last** column contains some "other" information.
Are you sure that you want to omit last **2** columns?

Comment: Yes. My first column is the number of the geometry, the second is the ID of the method I used to generate the geometry and the last column is actually empty. I get the information in the column -2